# How to stop a thread in a service

Tags: android, multithreading, android-service

Today I have a problem in my Android project. I use a Service with a thread in it to log location information in a period of 10s. However, when I change the screen orientation (Portrait -> Landscape), the period just messed up.

I think I may run another thread so that I got one more thread running behind once I rotate the screen. I have print log messages and it seems my guessing is right.

Here is my code:

```
public class LocationService extends Service
{
    public Location loc;
    public LocationService()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int id)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LocationService.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED )
                {
                    loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if(loc == null) // fall back to network if GPS is not available
                    {
                        loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    }
                    if(loc != null)
                    {
                        Timer timer = new Timer();
                        final String time = (new Date()).toString();
                        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void run()
                            {
                                Log.d(time, "hehe");
                                double currentLat = loc.getLatitude();
                                double currentLng = loc.getLongitude();
                                Intent done = new Intent();
                                done.setAction("location");
                                done.putExtra("currentLat", currentLat);
                                done.putExtra("currentLng", currentLng);
                                sendBroadcast(done);
                                //Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, String.valueOf(currentLat) + String.valueOf(currentlng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }, 10000, 10000);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, "Please allow app to access your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY; // stay running
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
//        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
//        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        return null;
    }

//    @Override
//    public void onDestroy()
//    {
//        Log.d("hehe","onDestroy");
//        super.onDestroy();
//    }

}
```

Here is the code for activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private LocalFragment localFragment;
    private ServerFragment serverFragment;
    private QueryFragment queryFragment;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;
    public SQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);

        //garb handlers
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        localFragment = (LocalFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_local);
        serverFragment = (ServerFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_server);
        queryFragment = (QueryFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_query);

        // initial visibility
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if(this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            // toolbar (must be put in checking orientation because landscape layout does not have toolbar here)
            toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.toolbar_title);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            transaction.show(localFragment);
            transaction.hide(serverFragment);
            transaction.hide(queryFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else // ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
        {
            transaction.hide(queryFragment); // landscape orientation does not need query function (?)
            transaction.show(localFragment);
            transaction.show(serverFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        // register network status receiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        NetworkStatusReceiver myNetworkReceiver = new NetworkStatusReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myNetworkReceiver, intentFilter);

        // start location service
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationService.class);
        intent.setAction("location");
        startService(intent);

        // register location receiver
        IntentFilter intentFilterLocation = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilterLocation.addAction("location");
        LocationReceiver myLocationReceiver = new LocationReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myLocationReceiver, intentFilterLocation);



    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        // handle click event
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_online)
        {
            transaction.hide(localFragment);
            transaction.hide(queryFragment);
            transaction.show(serverFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_offline)
        {
            transaction.hide(serverFragment);
            transaction.hide(queryFragment);
            transaction.show(localFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
        else // Query
        {
            transaction.hide(localFragment);
            transaction.hide(serverFragment);
            transaction.show(queryFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // receiver for network change action
    private class NetworkStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) // if receive network change event broadcast
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Network status changed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // why I cannot use another thread to do so? CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
//                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
//                {
//                    @Override
//                    public void run()
//                    {
                        int type = 0;
                        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(); // get current network type
                        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable())
                        {
                            type = networkInfo.getType();
                            String typeName = networkInfo.getTypeName(); // (?)
                            //serverFragment = (ServerFragment)fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_server);
                            if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) // wifi
                            {
                                WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
                                WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
                                Log.d("wifiInfo", wifiInfo.toString());
                                Log.d("SSID",wifiInfo.getSSID());
                                serverFragment.setNetworkStatusText("WIFI: " + wifiInfo.getSSID());    // thread issues here. WTF
                            } else if (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) // Cellar
                            {
                                serverFragment.setNetworkStatusText("Mobile Data");
                            } else // no network
                            {
                                serverFragment.setNetworkStatusText("No Network");
                            }
                        } else // no network
                        {
                            serverFragment.setNetworkStatusText("No Network");
                        }
//                    }
//                });
//                thread.start();
            }
        }
    }

    // receiver for location per 10s
    public class LocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("location"))
            {
                double currentLat = intent.getDoubleExtra("currentLat", 0.0);
                double currentLng = intent.getDoubleExtra("currentLng", 0.0);
                Date now = new Date();
                localFragment.addNewLocation(now, currentLat, currentLng); // add to list for listview

                // TODO: 11/5/16 implement SQLite insert
                dbHelper.addEntry(now, currentLat, currentLng);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Current Location: " + String.valueOf(currentLat) + ", " + String.valueOf(currentLng), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setNetworkStatus(String networkStatus)
    {
        serverFragment.setNetworkStatusText(networkStatus);
    }
}
```

My Question are:

1. It seems that the `onDestroy ()` method would not be called when rotate the screen?
2. A new `Service` will not be created when rotate the screen?
3. How can I stop the thread created previously? Or what is the best way to handle this problem?

Comment: you can use the bind service, by which you can access the thread object and then once done with the work in the thread , you can interrupt the thread i.e. stop the thread.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that the `onDestroy()` method would not be called when rotate the screen?

No, it isn't. Changing the screen orientation kills the `Activity` and creates a new one, but your `Service` is still running. Screen orientation has no effect on this.

> A new `Service` will not be created when rotate the screen?

No. A `Service` is essentially a singleton. Android will not create a new instance of your `Service` if there is already one running. However, `onStartCommand()` will be called again because your `Activity` calls `startService()` when it is created.

> How can I stop the thread created previously? Or what is the best way to handle this problem?

The easiest way to deal with this is to check in `onStartCommand()` if your thread is already running. If so, you don't need to start it again. Save a reference to your `Thread` in a member variable (a field) in your `Service` and call `isAlive()` on it to see if it is running.

Also, in `onDestroy()` you should make sure that your `Thread` shuts down, otherwise it will continue to run even after your `Service` is dead. To do that you should create a `boolean` member variable (field) in the `Thread`, which you check in each loop. In `onDestroy()` of your `Service`, set that `boolean` so that the `Thread` exits.